# IndexError: list index out of range; split is causing the issue probably

Tags: python

I am just two days to Python and also to this Forum. Please bear if my question looks silly. I tried searching the stack overflow, but couldn't correlate the info whats been given.

Please help me on this

```
   >>> import re
   >>> file=open("shortcuts","r")
   >>> for i in file:
   ...  i=i.split(' ',2)
   ...  if i[1] == '^/giftfordad$':
   ...   print i[1]
   ...
   ^/giftfordad$
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
   IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am receiving my desire output but along with list index out of range error.
My file shortcuts contains four columns which are delimited with SPACE.

Also please help me how to find the pattern if the value resides in a variable.
For example

```
var1=giftcard
```

How to find `^/var$` in my file. Thanks for help in advance.

From Jon's point, I arrive at this. But still looking for answer. the below gives me an empty result. Need some tweak in regex for [^/ and $]

```
    >>> import re
    >>> with open('shortcut','r') as fin:
    ...  lines =  (line for line in fin if line.strip() and not line.strip().startswith('#'))
    ...  for line in lines:
    ...   if re.match("^/giftfordad$",line):
    ...    print line
```

From my shell command, i arrive at the answer easily. Can somebody please write/correct this piece of code achieving the results, I'm looking for. Many thanks

```
    $grep "\^\/giftfordad\\$" shortcut
    RewriteRule ^/giftfordad$ /home/sathya/?id=456 [R,L]
```

Comment: Can you please show the content of your `shortcuts` file ?

Comment: Here is one sample
`RewriteRule ^/tv$ /home/sathya?id=123 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Having seen what you're trying to emulate - what you're after is `if '^/giftfordata$' in line`

Comment: My scope is to add a line of `RewriteRule ^/giftfordad$ /home/sathya/?id=456 [R,L]` to shortcut if `giftfordad` is not present in the second column of shortcut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the line you gave as an example, and here is what I found, hoping that fits your expectations (I understood you wanted to replace `^/tv$` by `^/giftfordad$` in column #2):

```
>>> s = 'RewriteRule ^/tv$ /home/sathya?id=123 [R=301,L]'
>>> parts = s.split()
>>> parts
['RewriteRule', '^/tv$', '/home/sathya?id=123', '[R=301,L]']
>>> if len(parts) > 1:
    part = parts[1]
    if not "^/giftfordad$" in part:
        print ' '.join([parts[0]] + ["^/giftfordad$"] +  parts[2:])
    else:
        print s    

RewriteRule ^/giftfordad$ /home/sathya?id=123 [R=301,L]
```

The line with `join` is the most complex: I recreate a list by concatenating:

- the 1st column unchanged
- the 2nd column replaced by `^/giftfordad$`
- the rest of the columns unchanged

`join` is then used to join all these elements as a string.

Comment: Thanks emmanuel. I reached what i desired... Voof!! My first python script is working... :D

Comment: :O) Just bought the Core Python Programming, written by Wesley Chun :) So much fun..

Answer (score 1):

In this:

```
i=i.split(' ',2)
if i[1] == '^/giftfordad$':
```

It would imply that `i` is now a list of length 1 (ie, there was no ' ' character to split on).

Also, it looks like you might be trying to use a regular expression and `if i[1] == '^/giftfordad$'` is not the way Python does those. That comparison would be written as:

```
if i[1] == '/giftfordad':
```

However, that's a completely valid string if you're grabbing it from a file of a list of regular expressions ;)

Just seen your example:

If you're processing an `.htaccess` like file, you'll want to ignore blank lines and presumably commented lines...

```
with open('shortcuts') as fin:
    lines =  (line for line in fin if line.strip() and not line.strip().startswith('#'))
    for line in lines:
        stuff = line.split(' ', 2)
        # etc...
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I am a guy from Shell script background and trying to rewrite my code in Python.
This is what I'm trying to achieve in Python. `awk '{print $2}' shortcuts | grep "\^\/giftfordad\$"`